# Passing props from one step to another (steppers) in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I am using steppers in vue. I am creating an agency in step 1 and on step 2 I am displaying the agency details. The issue is that the agency details don't appear on step 2 until I refresh page after going on step 2. Is there a way to pass agency as a prop from agency.vue to event.vue so that I dont need to refresh the page to make the agency details appear on step 2.

stepper.vue

```
<template>
    <div >
      <v-stepper v-model="e1">
        <v-stepper-header>
          <v-stepper-step :complete="e1 > 1" step="1">Agency</v-stepper-step>

          <v-divider></v-divider>

          <v-stepper-step :complete="e1 > 2" step="2">Event</v-stepper-step>

          <v-divider></v-divider>
        </v-stepper-header>

        <v-stepper-items>
          <v-stepper-content step="1">
            <Agency @next="goTo(2, true)"></Agency>
          </v-stepper-content>

          <v-stepper-content step="2">
            <Event/>
          </v-stepper-content>
        </v-stepper-items>
      </v-stepper>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import Agency from 'parties/agency';
import Event from 'events/event';

export default {
  components: {
    Agency,
    Event
  },
  data () {
    return {
      e1: 0,
      agency: {
        id: '',
        name: '',
        phone_number: ''
      }
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.step = 1;
    this.getAgency();
  },
  methods: {    
    getAgency() {
      this.$axios.get('/agency.json')
      .then(response => {
        if (Object.keys(response.data).length > 0) {
          this.agency = response.data;
        }
      })
    },
    goTo(step, can) {
      if (can) {
        this.e1 = step;
      }
    },
  }
};
</script>
```

agency.vue

```
<template>
  <v-card>
    <v-form :model='agency'>     
      <v-layout row wrap>
        <v-flex xs12 sm12 lg12 >
          <v-layout row wrap>
            <v-flex xs12 md6 class="add-col-padding-right">
              <v-text-field
                label='Agency Name'
                v-model='agency.name'>
              </v-text-field>
            </v-flex>
          </v-layout>
          <v-layout row wrap>
            <v-flex xs12 md6 class="add-col-padding-right">
              <v-text-field
                label='Agency Phone Number'
                v-model='agency.phone_number'>
              </v-text-field>
            </v-flex>
          </v-layout>
          <v-layout row wrap>
            <div>
              <v-btn @click.prevent='saveAgency'>Save</v-btn>
            </div>
          </v-layout>
        </v-flex>
      </v-layout>           
    </v-form>
    <v-btn @click.prevent='nextStep'>
     Next
    </v-btn>
  </v-card>
</template>

<script>

export default {

  data: function () {
    return {
      agency: {
        id: '',
        name: '',
        phone_number: ''
      }
    };
  },
  created: function() {
    this.getAgency();
  },
  methods: {
    nextStep() {
     this.$emit('next');
    },
    getAgency() {
      this.$axios.get('/agency.json')
      .then(response => {
        if (Object.keys(response.data).length > 0) {
          this.agency = response.data;          
        }
      })
    },
    saveAgency() {
      this.$axios.post('/agencies.json', { agency: this.agency })
      .then(response => {
      });           
    },    
  }
};
</script>
```

event.vue

```
<template>
  <v-card class="mb-12">

    <v-form :model='agency'>
      {{ agency.name }}<br/>
      {{ agency.phone_number }}<br/>          
    </v-form>
  </v-card>
</template>

<script>

  export default {
  data: function () {
    return {
      agency: {
        id: '',
        name: '',
        phone_number: ''
      },
      event_final: false
    };
  },

  created: function() {
    this.getAgency();
  },
  methods: {    
    getAgency() {
      this.$axios.get('/agency.json')
      .then(response => {
        if (Object.keys(response.data).length > 0) {
          this.agency = response.data;
          if (this.agency.name === "XYZ") {
           this.event_final = true;
          }
        }
      }).
      then(() => {
      });
    },   
  }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have `Agency` emit the details in its `next` event, capture them at the parent and pass them as a prop to `Event`.

Given you load the initial data in `stepper.vue`, you can also pass that into `Agency` for editing

For example

```js
// agency.vue
props: { editAgency: Object },
data () {
  return { agency: this.editAgency } // initialise with prop data
},
methods: {
  nextStep() {
    this.$emit('next', { ...this.agency }) // using spread to break references
  },
  // etc, no need for getAgency() here though
}
```

```html
<!-- stepper.vue -->
<Agency :edit-agency="agency" @next="nextAgency"></Agency>
<!-- snip -->
<Event :agency="agency" />
```

```js
// stepper.vue
methods: {
  nextAgency (agency) {
    this.agency = agency
    this.goTo(2, true)
  },
```

```js
// event.vue
export default {
  props: { agency: Object } // no need for a local "data" copy of agency, just use the prop
}
```

Comment: Phil your answer almost solves my problem, its just that, like I have getAgency() in events.vue file where in the response I have a condition if the name of the agency is "XYZ" then set event_final to true. How would that be possible on the object that is coming as a prop?